# Unable to build MySQL++ library -- mysqlpp_d.dll linkage errors

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, mysql++

I'm trying to build MySQL++ library in Windows via Visual Studio 2013 (MSVC-12.0). This is what I've done:

- Installed on my computer [MySQL Community Server 5.6.16](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-installer-community-5.6.16.0.msi) via "Full installation"
- Downloaded [mysql++-3.2.1](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/releases/mysql++-3.2.1.tar.gz), unpacked it
- Opened a file named "mysql++.sln" from directory "mysql++-3.2.1\vc2005\" via Visual Studio 2013 (unfortunately, this library doesn't have native solution for Visual Studio 2013), converted it
- Changed paths in the "Additional Include Directories" (in my case it's "e:\software\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1.3\include\") and "Additional Library Directories" ("e:\software\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1.3\lib\") in the "mysqlpp" project settings
- Tried to build this project -- "mysqlpp_d.lib" was built successful, while building of "mysqlpp_d.dll" gave me the following errors:

```
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_init@0
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_init@0
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_init@0 referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl mysqlpp::DBDriver::thread_start(void)" (?thread_start@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@SA_NXZ)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_init@0
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_init@0
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_init@0
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_end@0 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row>::construct(class mysqlpp::Row *,class mysqlpp::Row const &" (?construct@?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@QAEXPAVRow@mysqlpp@@ABV34@@Z)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_end@0
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_end@0
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_end@0
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_end@0
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_end@0
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_rows@4
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_rows@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_rows@4 referenced in function "public: unsigned __int64 __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::num_rows(struct st_mysql_res *)const " (?num_rows@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QBE_KPAUst_mysql_res@@@Z)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_rows@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_rows@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_rows@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_fields@4 referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_Vector_alloc<0,struct std::_Vec_base_types<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > >::_Vector_alloc<0,struct std::_Vec_base_types<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > >(class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> const &" (??0?$_Vector_alloc@$0A@U?$_Vec_base_types@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QAE@ABV?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@1@@Z)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_fields@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_fields@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_fields@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_fields@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_fields@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field_direct@8
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field_direct@8
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field_direct@8 referenced in function "public: struct st_mysql_field * __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::fetch_field(struct st_mysql_res *,unsigned int)const " (?fetch_field@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QBEPAUst_mysql_field@@PAUst_mysql_res@@I@Z)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field_direct@8
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field_direct@8
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field_direct@8
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_count@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Vector_alloc<0,struct std::_Vec_base_types<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > >::_Alloc_proxy(void)" (?_Alloc_proxy@?$_Vector_alloc@$0A@U?$_Vec_base_types@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_count@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_count@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_count@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_count@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_count@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_affected_rows@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Vector_alloc<0,struct std::_Vec_base_types<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > >::_Alloc_proxy(void)" (?_Alloc_proxy@?$_Vector_alloc@$0A@U?$_Vec_base_types@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_affected_rows@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_affected_rows@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_affected_rows@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_affected_rows@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_affected_rows@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_insert_id@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Vector_alloc<0,struct std::_Vec_base_types<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > >::_Alloc_proxy(void)" (?_Alloc_proxy@?$_Vector_alloc@$0A@U?$_Vec_base_types@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_insert_id@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_insert_id@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_insert_id@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_insert_id@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_insert_id@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_errno@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Vector_alloc<0,struct std::_Vec_base_types<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > >::_Free_proxy(void)" (?_Free_proxy@?$_Vector_alloc@$0A@U?$_Vec_base_types@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_errno@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_errno@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_errno@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_errno@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_errno@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_error@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Vector_alloc<0,struct std::_Vec_base_types<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > >::_Free_proxy(void)" (?_Free_proxy@?$_Vector_alloc@$0A@U?$_Vec_base_types@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_error@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_error@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_error@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_error@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_error@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_id@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Vector_alloc<0,struct std::_Vec_base_types<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > >::_Free_proxy(void)" (?_Free_proxy@?$_Vector_alloc@$0A@U?$_Vec_base_types@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_id@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_id@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_id@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_id@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_id@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_select_db@8 referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >(unsigned int)" (??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@I@Z)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_select_db@8
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_select_db@8
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_select_db@8
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_select_db@8
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_select_db@8
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_query@12
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_query@12
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_query@12 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::execute(char const *,unsigned int)" (?execute@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QAE_NPBDI@Z)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_query@12
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_query@12
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_query@12
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_store_result@4 referenced in function __catch$??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@I@Z$0
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_store_result@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_store_result@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_store_result@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_store_result@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_store_result@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_use_result@4 referenced in function __catch$??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@I@Z$0
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_use_result@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_use_result@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_use_result@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_use_result@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_use_result@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_refresh@8 referenced in function __catch$??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@I@Z$0
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_refresh@8
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_refresh@8
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_refresh@8
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_refresh@8
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_refresh@8
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_kill@8 referenced in function __catch$??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@I@Z$0
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_kill@8
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_kill@8
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_kill@8
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_kill@8
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_kill@8
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_set_server_option@8
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_set_server_option@8
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_set_server_option@8 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::set_option(enum enum_mysql_set_option)" (?set_option@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QAE_NW4enum_mysql_set_option@@@Z)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_set_server_option@8
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_set_server_option@8
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_set_server_option@8
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_ping@4 referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >(unsigned int,class mysqlpp::Row const &" (??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@IABVRow@mysqlpp@@@Z)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_ping@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_ping@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_ping@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_ping@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_ping@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_stat@4
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_stat@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_stat@4 referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::server_status(void)" (?server_status@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_stat@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_stat@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_stat@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_server_info@4 referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >(unsigned int,class mysqlpp::Row const &,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> const &" (??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@IABVRow@mysqlpp@@ABV?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@1@@Z)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_server_info@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_server_info@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_server_info@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_server_info@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_server_info@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_client_info@0
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_client_info@0
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_client_info@0 referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::client_version(void)const " (?client_version@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_client_info@0
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_client_info@0
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_client_info@0
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_host_info@4 referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >(class std::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > const &" (??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_host_info@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_host_info@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_host_info@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_host_info@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_host_info@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_proto_info@4
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_proto_info@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_proto_info@4 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::protocol_version(void)" (?protocol_version@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QAEHXZ)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_proto_info@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_proto_info@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_get_proto_info@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_options@12 referenced in function __catch$??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z$0
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_options@12
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_options@12
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_options@12
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_options@12
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_options@12
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> ssqls2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4 referenced in function __catch$??$?5DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@AAD@Z$0
1> transaction.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> vallist.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> qparms.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> row.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> manip.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> mysql++.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> mystring.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> field_names.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> field_types.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_data_seek@12 referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >(class std::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > const &,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> const &" (??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@ABV01@ABV?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@1@@Z)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_data_seek@12
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_data_seek@12
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_data_seek@12
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_data_seek@12
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_data_seek@12
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_seek@8
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_seek@8
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_seek@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::field_seek(struct st_mysql_res *,unsigned int)const " (?field_seek@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QBEXPAUst_mysql_res@@I@Z)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_seek@8
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_seek@8
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_field_seek@8
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_row@4 referenced in function __catch$??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@ABV01@ABV?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@1@@Z$0
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_row@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_row@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_row@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_row@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_row@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_lengths@4
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_lengths@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_lengths@4 referenced in function "public: unsigned long const * __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::fetch_lengths(struct st_mysql_res *)const " (?fetch_lengths@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QBEPBKPAUst_mysql_res@@@Z)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_lengths@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_lengths@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_lengths@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >::_Construct_n(unsigned int,class mysqlpp::Row const *)" (?_Construct_n@?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAEXIPBVRow@mysqlpp@@@Z)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_field@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_escape_string@12
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_escape_string@12
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_escape_string@12 referenced in function "public: static unsigned int __cdecl mysqlpp::DBDriver::escape_string_no_conn(char *,char const *,unsigned int)" (?escape_string_no_conn@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@SAIPADPBDI@Z)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_escape_string@12
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_escape_string@12
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_escape_string@12
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_escape_string@16 referenced in function __catch$?_Construct_n@?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAEXIPBVRow@mysqlpp@@@Z$0
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_escape_string@16
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_escape_string@16
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_escape_string@16
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_escape_string@16
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_escape_string@16
1> result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_more_results@4 referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> >(class std::vector<class mysqlpp::Row,class std::allocator<class mysqlpp::Row> > &&" (??0?$vector@VRow@mysqlpp@@V?$allocator@VRow@mysqlpp@@@std@@@std@@QAE@$$QAV01@@Z)
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_more_results@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_more_results@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_more_results@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_more_results@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_more_results@4
1> result.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_next_result@4
1> sqlstream.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_next_result@4
1> connection.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_next_result@4 referenced in function "public: enum mysqlpp::DBDriver::nr_code __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::next_result(void)" (?next_result@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QAE?AW4nr_code@12@XZ)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_next_result@4
1> options.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_next_result@4
1> query.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_next_result@4
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_info@4 referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::query_info(void)" (?query_info@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::connect_prepare(void)" (?connect_prepare@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@IAE_NXZ)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_ssl_set@24 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::enable_ssl(char const *,char const *,char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?enable_ssl@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QAE_NPBD0000@Z)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_connect@32 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::connect(struct st_mysql const &" (?connect@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QAE_NABUst_mysql@@@Z)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_shutdown@8 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::shutdown(void)" (?shutdown@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QAE_NXZ)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_thread_safe@0 referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl mysqlpp::DBDriver::thread_aware(void)" (?thread_aware@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@SA_NXZ)
1> dbdriver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_close@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall mysqlpp::DBDriver::disconnect(void)" (?disconnect@DBDriver@mysqlpp@@QAEXXZ)
1> E:\libs\mysql++-3.2.1\vc2005\Debug\mysqlpp_d.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 42 unresolved externals
```

I've already tried to search the root of this problem, but didn't find anything useful in my case.

What am I doing wrong? how can I fix it?